# smalltalk public initialize

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo

Is there any way to "hide" initialize method so it couldn't be called after construction?

I would like something like:

```
Class>>new: params
  ^super newInstance initializedBy: [
    "actual initialization code"
]
```

Comment: are you trying to create a singleton?

Comment: smalltalk is a 'consenting adult' language. if someone is calling your initialize method after that fact, you have bigger problems than that.

Comment: new is a class method that creates an instance, sets up its memory etc. initialization is then done on the instance itself because you are initializing an instance. if you want to not have an initalization method in the common smalltalk style. well... see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Class>>initializeInstance: anInstance
  anInstance instVarNamed: #i put: 1.
  anInstance instVarNamed: #j put: 2.
```

but, you still have an initialize method of sorts but now it is on the class side and doesn't really do what you want. however.. you could try:

```
Class>>new: params
  ^super newInstance initializedBy: [ anInstance |
    anInstance instVarNamed: #i put: 1.
    anInstance someMethodCalledOnInitalization.
]
```

and on the instance side:

```
initializedBy: anInitializationBlock

  anInitializationBlock value: self.
```

I think that gets at the general idea of what you wanted. I don't think its worth the effort as I can just reach in using instVarNamed and change your object around. The smalltalk convention is simple... no one from the outside should call anything in your initialization method category w/o a really good understanding of why they are doing it.

You could also keep it all on your class side w:

```
Class>>new: params
  anInstance := super newInstance.
  ^ self initialize: anInstance using: [ anInstance |
      anInstance instVarNamed: #j put: 1.
  ].

Class>>initialize: anInstance using: aBlock
  aBlock value: anInstance.
  ^ anInstance.
```

Comment: That access to variables is how most of the tools work. For example, changing the value of variable in an object via the inspector. Features like that lead to incredible productivity boosters like debugger driven development. it is also incredibly important when migrating existing instances of class in an image if you change the shape of the class. for example, if you add a new instance variable counter to class Foo, and you already have 10 foos in existence, you can use instanceVarNamed: #counter put: 100. to give it an initial value on those that already exist.

Comment: if you want, we could take this to email and i'd be happy to walk you through some of the metaprogramming stuff that is available in smalltalk and we can talk about why you want to do what you want to do etc.

Comment: No I never got it. Sorry I didn't notice this til now. Try again. I'll keep an eye out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for Seuss, my dependency injection framework, which gives you a great deal of control over the initialization process (and, by default, calls initialize AFTER construction parameters are passed into setters). It's still unreleased, though.

To answer your question, without using Seuss, you can overwrite new, so that it does not call `initialize:`

```
MyClass>>new
   ^ self basicNew
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you're asking if you can make a method private. The answer is yes and no :) The convention in Smalltalk is to put "private" methods in the "private" category. This is a signal to outside users that it's not to be used, but nothing prevents them from actually using it anyway. In practice this seems to work fine.

Is that what you were asking? If not, some more details would help.

Comment: IMHO all methods should be public, so it's not what I want. I want something I've shown - define class method which calls closure (which is not callable from outside) - the problem is I need access to instance variables in that closure. (and because new is class-side, I don't know how to do that)

Answer (score 0):

You can also NOT implement #initialize and whatever you wanted to put there but not called from #new, you put it in another method with another name.

Comment: i think he has a problem with instance initialization existing on an instance which isn't going to end well in terms of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of different ways of achieving the end goal,

a) add 'initialized' instance variable and skip #initialize when set to true,

```
   Contact>>initialize  
     initialized == true ifTrue: [^self].  
     enabled := false.  
     lastModified := Timestamp now.  
     initialized := true.
```

b) add a test case that runs a rewrite search through your code and counts the senders of #initialize that aren't in the #new method(s) of its own class hierarchy. In fact, if your own classes inherit from a common model, you should really only have one sender of #initialize, and that can be easily asserted in a test case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One thing you also need to keep in mind that if someone _really_ wanted to, they could add their own writer of 'initialized', set it to false and re-run #initialize, so you're never going to make it bullet-proof, but as you'll find out soon enough, the power of Smalltalk comes exactly from the fact that folks can tinker with the system in ways that original developers may not have intended.

Comment: I just don't want initialize method on instance-side, it should be on class-side but I just can't find way how to access instance vars so I can initialize them on class-side (let's say using closure as I've shown). Yes I know about that - and I like the ability to bend language when necessary, but this is not something you usually do. (I hope)

Comment: you cant. in your example, the block [] would be passed to a new instance. a class doesnt have instance variables. only instances do.

Comment: Kamil, you have to keep in mind that you'll never fully protect your instances from unintended manipulation, so you should instead focus on the API that works best for **you** and simply put methods that shouldn't be used by others into protocols that indicate 'private' in their name ((nil -> nil) instVarNamed: 'key' put: #zork; yourself  -->  #zork -> nil)

Comment: I just wanted to know if it's possible without modifying language, or some core classes.

Answer (score 0):

instance methods:

```
initialize
    ... do what you need to do ...
    ... then ...
    self blockInitialize

blockInitialize
    self changeClassTo:(self class subclassWithoutInitialize)
```

class methods:

```
isSubclassWithoutInitialize
    ^ false

subclassWithoutInitialize
    ^ self subclasses 
        detect:[:cls | cls isSubclassWithoutInitialize]
        ifNone:[
            newClass := self 
                subclass:(self name,'WithoutInitialize')
                instanceVariableNames:''
                classVariableNames:''
                category:'*hidden*'.
            newClass class compile:'isSubclassWithoutInitialize ^ true].
            newClass compile:'initialize ^ self].
            newClass.
        ].
```

tried it in my (ST/X) image - works!
Of course, the helper methods could be placed higher up in the hierarchy...